# Cómo conectar con una BBDD MS Access alojada en un servidor desde PHP

Tags: php, ms-access

Tenía mi programa PHP y mi BD MS Access en local ya configurada. Ahora tengo que meterla en el servidor. He llevado el programa al servidor, he configurado las herramientas administrativas, pero al ejecutar la conexión me da el siguiente fallo:

> "Warning: odbc_connect(): y ya me muestra la dirección dónde está el
> fallo". Me muestra el siguiente fallo: no se encuentra el nombre del origen de datos y no se especifica ningún controlador predeterminado".

Sin embargo, tengo el driver instalado y el DSN configurado.

El caso es que no veo dónde está el fallo. Le he puesto en las herramientas administrativas el mismo nombre a la DSN que a la conexión a la BBDD en local y el código es el siguiente:

```
$conMSAccess=odbc_connect("nombre-dsn", "", "");
$resultMSAccess=""; 

    if($conMSAccess){
        $resultMSAccess="Connected to MS Access DB";
    } else {
       $resultMSAccess= "Problems MS Access";
    }
```

¿Me falta algo por configurar? ¿O dónde está el fallo? Estoy desplegando el programa en el servidor en XAMPP, no sé si quizás el problema puede ir por ahí, porque en local me va perfectamente desplegando el programa en XAMPP. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Imprime el mensaje de error **temporalmente**  y agrégalo a la pregunta para tener una idea del motivo del fallo. Puedes usar `odbc_errormsg()` para ello.

Comment: Me dice que "no se encuentra el nombre del origen de datos y no se especifica ningún controlador predeterminado". Sin embargo, tengo el driver instalado y el DSN configurado.

Comment: Ese error está ligado a veces al problema de los 32 bits o los 64 bits. Por ejemplo, si tu PHP trabaja en 32 bits, debes agregar los controladores de 32 bits, y si trabaja en 64 bits, los controladores de 64 bits. Y debes asegurarte que la ruta de la base de datos que estás poniendo es correcta.

Comment: El Access es de 64 bits y el controlador y el tema de las herramientas administrativas también estoy usando el de 64 bits. La ruta de los datos es correcta.

Comment: El mensaje de error es inequívoco: o tienes un problema con la fuente de datos y/o tienes un problema con el controlador. Debes verificar eso.

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias.